# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception PharException with message manifest

Tags: symfony, command-line, symfony-2.1, composer-php

while trying to install  `composer.phar` through command line  , got an error

```
 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message manifest cannot be larger than 100 mb in phar
```

please support me to solve this problem, i am trying to installing `symfony2.1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears you got a corrupted phar for some reason. Try downloading a new one from https://getcomposer.org/download/ - if the CLI instructions do not work out for you you can just download the last snapshot by hand from https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar