# Composer Download is Corrupt on Mac

Tags: php, macos

I have been trying to install Composer so I can upgrade to Symfony 2.1 but the download fails when I run curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php. The error message is:

`Downloading...
The download is corrupt, retrying...
Downloading...
The download is corrupt, retrying...
Downloading...
The download is corrupt (phar error: "/Users/andrew.tarry/composer.phar" is a corrupted tar file (checksum mismatch of file "#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of Composer.
 *
 * (c) Nils Adermann <naderman@nade")), aborting.`

I am using a Mac on OSX 10.8.2 and PHP 5.4.8. Does anyone know the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Then download the file from the website directly: [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/)

its only a **.phar** archive. You can run it with PHP

```
php /path/to/your/file/composer.phar options
```

or if you put the file to `/usr/local/bin` (i hope its the same on Mac) you can run them directly. Without the path.

Comment: Thanks Stony but unfortinatly that does not seem to fix the problem. The downloaded file thowns this exception `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar error: "/Users/andrew.tarry/composer/composer.phar" is a corrupted tar file (checksum mismatch of file "#!/usr/bin/env php`. I assume it's related to first problem but I'm not sure

Comment: Hmm? The curl downloader only download the file form the website. So which error do you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799154/php-fatal-error-uncaught-exception-pharexception-with-message-manifest

Comment: Hmm its everytime the same answer. Perhaps its a problem with PHP 5.4.8. Its relativ new version. Perhaps you try a 5.3 CLI Version.